# How to access Lucene POS attribute (Japanese Kuromoji analyzer)

Tags: lucene

I am trying to tokenize Japanese text and extract **part of speech attributes** as [explained on the kuromoji website](http://www.atilika.org/).

Kuromoji / Lucene comes with a [PartOfSpeechAttributeImpl](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-kuromoji/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ja/tokenattributes/PartOfSpeechAttributeImpl.html) attribute implementation, which is supposed to provide POS data but I am not able to extract that - i get a NullPointerException on the pos.getPartOfSpeech() line. The CharTermAttribute prints. What am I missing, doing wrongly?

```
    String content = "こんばんは 今日寒かったですね 今日、頂いたお菓子があまりにも美味しくて 上り羊羹 御利益ありそうな、ネーミング ぷるんぷるんの、上品な水羊羹です！ そして、スイーツもう一品！ 先日アップしたお友達の干し芋。";

    Analyzer analyzer = new JapaneseAnalyzer();
    TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("TEXT", content);

    Iterator<AttributeImpl> it = stream.getAttributeImplsIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        AttributeImpl attr = it.next();
        System.out.println(attr.getClass());
    }
    CharTermAttribute term = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    PartOfSpeechAttributeImpl pos = stream.getAttribute(PartOfSpeechAttributeImpl.class);

    stream.reset();
    while (stream.incrementToken()) {
        System.out.println("[" + term.toString() + "]: ");
        System.out.println(pos.getPartOfSpeech());
    }
```

The first while loop actually shows that the PartOfSpeechAttribute is already added to the token stream. This is the print stmt output:

```
   class org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PackedTokenAttributeImpl
   class org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.tokenattributes.BaseFormAttributeImpl
   class org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.tokenattributes.PartOfSpeechAttributeImpl
   class org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.tokenattributes.ReadingAttributeImpl
   class org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.tokenattributes.InflectionAttributeImpl
   class org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.KeywordAttributeImpl
```

I have also followed the advice from other Stackoverflow posts to addAttribute() instead of getAttribute() for the PartOfSpeechAttributeImpl. But that gives me an IllegalArgumentException (although this ArributeImpl implements Lucene Attribute):

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addAttribute() only accepts an interface that extends Attribute, but 
   org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.tokenattributes.PartOfSpeechAttributeImpl does not fulfil this contract.
      at   org.apache.lucene.util.AttributeSource.addAttribute(AttributeSource.java:210)
      at ...
```

FYI: Currently we use Lucene 6.0.0. Indexation and search works fine in Japanese, as the Kuromoji package is included by default in Lucene distributions (you just need to pick the JapaneseAnalyzer). This tokenization process happens outside indexation or search and is therefore not tied to a specific field; it is used for a different purpose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PartOfSpeechAttributeImpl is not correct. It should be PartOfSpeechAttribute

```
    PartOfSpeechAttribute pattr = stream.addAttribute(PartOfSpeechAttribute.class);
    try {
        stream.reset();
        while (stream.incrementToken()) {
            cattr.toString();
            String pos[] = pattr.getPartOfSpeech().split("-");
            Token token = new Token(stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString(), pos);
            result.add(token);
        }
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return result;
    } finally {
        analyzer.close();
    }
    return result;
```